# changing contents of array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This seems like it should be easy but i've spent way too much time on it. Hopefully someone can help.

```
char *labels[] = { "apple", "orange" }; // each items inside label is string literal. We can't change them-
```

Look at the below

```
char a[]="hi";
char b[]="hello";
char *name[]={a,b};//each item inside name is not string literal rite??
*name="bye";
puts(a);
```

I thought output will be `bye` since i changed the content of `a[]` using `*name="bye"`

But the output is still `hi`. why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`char *name[]={a,b};//each item inside name is not string literal rite??` - not quite, each element is a pointer to a `char`.

So `name` is an array of pointers. `*name="bye"` changes what the first of those pointers change to. It doesn't change the memory that the old pointer pointed to.

If you wanted to do that you would use `strncpy` in general, but note that here you don't have a large enough array to do that.

(I would also have expected your compiler to give you a warning about assigning a `const char *` to a `char*` for `*name="bye"`)

Before `*name="bye"`:

[image: State before]

After `*name="bye"`:

[image: State after]

Comment: When i debugged i found what you are saying is happening. But `*name` has the address of `a[]` rite? Any modification to `*name` has to be reflected in `a[]` rite?. Nope i didn't get any warnings.

Comment: No. `*name` is a pointer still, that points to `a`. `*name` changes what the pointer points to.

Comment: So now that *name has changed to point to something else, looking for b and expecting it to be "hello" isn't really valid, right?

Comment: `b` isn't changed at all. It's still valid, it' still pointed to by the 2nd element of `name`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.  Can you explain why this doesn't work `**name="hi"`

Comment: `**name` is a `char`, `"hi"` is `const char[3]`. There's no legal assignment possible there. That's now how string copying works in C.